# deploying kony app in iphone device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios4, temenos-quantum

I am facing some problem in kony platform. I can able to deploy the iphone app created using kony platform in simulator by using their guide. If i tried to deploy same app in iphone device i am getting some errors.

```
Undefined symbols:


 "___divmodsi4", referenced from:
      -[KonySlotView addImagesToGallery:urlString:userDataSize:userData:] in libkonylib.a(KonySlotView.o)
      -[KonyImageGallery addImagesToGallery:urlString:userDataSize:userData:] in libkonylib.a(KonyImageGallery.o)
  "_objc_terminate", referenced from:
      -[KonyWebSQLTransaction performTransaction:SQLTransactionErrorCallback:SQLVoidCallback:IsReadTransaction:] in libkonylib.a(KonyWebSQL.o)
      -[VMAppDelegate konyApplicationDidFinishLaunching:] in libkonylib.a(VMAppDelegate.o)
      -[VMAppDelegate KonyExecute] in libkonylib.a(VMAppDelegate.o)
      +[ClosureExecuter executeClosure:] in libkonylib.a(lglobals.o)
  "___udivmodsi4", referenced from:
      -[KonyImageGallery getPreferredHeight] in libkonylib.a(KonyImageGallery.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

error seems like some problem while linking library. can anyone help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: What compiler/xcode are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You will never resolve this, unless you contact Kony developer team, that I can tell you from experience. The issue is with the Kony API that is used to do the mappings with Lua code to objective-c code.

Comment: Oscar, has anything in KONY worked for you at all ever? WYSIWIG designer is trash, "widgets" never look exactly right, no proper support for margins, DIPs on Android. Not to mention that all service calls fail in an unhandled way and crash the app that does not even restart afterwards when cell network is not there. Yeah, and KONY enjoys HUGE user community (joking)

Comment: @itadapter Well to be fair it "works" if you are doing very simple things, otherwise my experience is about the same as you. I am no longer using it, but yes the User community is bad and there are many issues with the platform, though not much more than in other cross-platform tools, I do native only now.

Comment: "do native now" - could not agree more. I found that simple approaches like PhoneGap+jQMobile work well for business-centric apps if you code it carefully/lightly (not many scripts etc..). Anything that touches sound, video, custom controls - alas, only natively